# Trying to Import an XML file into a MS SQL table using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

I am trying to import an XML file into a MS SQL table using PowerShell, I have modified a PowerShell script I already had that worked fine but could do with some help as the new XML file has multiple entries for some elements.( I have included a sample of the XML file)

Table layout is below and as is a sample of the file I am trying to import and also my script I am trying to modify to get working.

Table layout is:

```
------------------------------
:supplier_id : name : Symbol :
```

and here is an part of the XML file itself

```xml
<SupplierMapping supplier_id="4536" name="Joby">
    <Symbol>Joby</Symbol>
</SupplierMapping>
<SupplierMapping supplier_id="4537" name="ACT">
    <Symbol>ACT</Symbol>
    <Symbol>ADVANCED CABLE TECH</Symbol>
    <Symbol>ADVANCED CABLE TECHNOLOGY</Symbol>
    <Symbol>IEC LOCK</Symbol>
</SupplierMapping>
```

As you can see some supplier id's and names will have multiple `<Symbol>` names so I would like to have multiple entries in my table for those, however the script I have modified only seems to pull in the supplier_id and name elements and misses the `<Symbol>` part entirely. any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```bsh
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine

[String]$global:connectionString = "Data Source=Apps2\Apps2;Initial Catalog=DTEDATA;Integrated Security=SSPI";
[System.Data.DataTable]$global:dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
[System.Xml.XmlTextReader]$global:xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\Scripts\icecat\supplier_mapping.xml");
[Int32]$global:batchSize = 100;

function Add-FileRow() {
    $newRow = $dt.NewRow();
    $null = $dt.Rows.Add($newRow);
    $newRow["supplier_id"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("supplier_id");
    $newRow["name"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("name");
    $newRow["Symbol"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Symbol");
}

# init data table schema
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Supplier_Mapping_Test WHERE 0 = 1", $global:connectionString);
$null = $da.Fill($global:dt);
$bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($global:connectionString);
$bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Supplier_Mapping_Test";

$recordCount = 0;

while ($xmlReader.Read() -eq $true) {
    if (($xmlReader.NodeType -eq [System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element) -and ($xmlReader.Name -eq "SupplierMapping"))
        Add-FileRow -xmlReader $xmlReader;
        $recordCount += 1;
        if (($recordCount % $global:batchSize) -eq 0) {
            $bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
            $dt.Rows.Clear();
            Write-Host "$recordCount file elements processed so far";
        }
    }
}

if ($dt.Rows.Count -gt 0) {
    $bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
}

$bcp.Close();
$xmlReader.Close();

Write-Host "$recordCount file elements imported ";

catch {
    throw;
}
```

Comment: once you have the file loaded into your `$xmlReader`variable, do you see the items in that structure? i ask because the the problem can be at the import OR at the point where you add it into the data table.

Comment: Hi Lee thanks for the reply, I am very new to powershell and am just trying to update an existing script that was written by someone else. obviously a very newbie question, how do I show the contents of the $xmlReader variable so I can see if the data is in there ?

Comment: Using an XmlReader is the hardest way to read XML in .NET, as it's forward-only.  Try using an XDocument instead, and you can have random access to the XML document.

Comment: sorry if I sound very ignorant but are you saying use XDocument in my powershell script instead of XmlReader ?

Comment: Your XML sample is broken (multiple root elements), as is your PowerShell code (missing curly bracket, catch without try). Aside from that, `<Symbol>` is not an attribute in the first place, so `$xmlReader.GetAttribute("Symbol")` will not work at all. You need to select the child nodes of the current node, and you'll need a loop, because there apparently can be multiple child nodes.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, I presumed it wouldn't be as easy as changing the script I had as <Symbol> is a child to <SupplierMapping> and has multiple entries, hence the loop. do you have any links to any suggested reading, again Its hard to put what I want into words as I am new to this, thanks anyway

Comment: Unless you have a huge XML file it's usually simpler to read the entire file and then use `SelectNodes()` with XPath expressions. [stackoverflow://\[powershell\]+\[xml\]+select+nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+%5Bxml%5D+select+nodes)

Comment: thanks I will check that out, the only reason I was going the was I did was that I already had a script written for a different file and thought it would be easier to change that, but as you pointed out the multiple entries are what has been causing the problems